# Localhost access via internet,tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, localhost, port, forwarding

I'm using Apache Tomcat server. I have my code in JSP and running. I'm able to access my pages through LAN connection from other computers. What I want to know is how can I access my pages from other computers connected to internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about having the computer which run the web server Apache not only connected to the internet and running the server, but also having root forwarded from  the ouside at 8080 port from its modem. It's also foundamental to have a public and static address.

Comment: Can you explain how to open a port for forwarding.

Comment: Yes, you must access from the browser of your computer to the modem which connects it to internet. When you access, you must go to the advanced options of your modem. How to access to this particular item of the menù option depends on the brand and the model of your modem. Then you must add a particular permission (a port forwarding) specifying in your modem advanced options that every http request on port 80 (if it's php Apache) or every request on port 8080 (if it's java Server Tomcat) must be forwarded to the LOCAL IP address of the computer where you have your server active.

Comment: Currently I am using Apache Tomcat server 9.0 with port number as 8080.

Comment: I am able to access the localhost using my static ip address of server along with port number through a router.I am using D-link router 600m.Could anyone share how to port forward to my ip address